# Most efficient way to iterate over hash values from two separate hash keys

Tags: ruby

I have hash value:

```
my_hash = {"host_names"=>["batman", "robin"], "files"=>["file1", "file2", "file3"]}
```

I need to iterate over each hostname, and then pull the same logs from each host.

Other than:

```
my_hash.each do |k, v|
  k["host_names].each do |hostname|
    k["log"].each do |log|
      get_log_file(host, log)
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you ask "Is there a more efficient way to do this?" your question becomes off-topic for Stack Overflow, and becomes on-topic for [codereview.se].

Comment: Your code is not syntactically valid.

Comment: Yea.. I missed some things on the logic, however I hope I was still able to promote the general idea.

Comment: @ Tin Man, The reason I didn't send to Code review was because this was not the actual logic I was using, and just an excerpt from the program. I figured this was more of a how to. I do agree I used poor verbage. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like so:

```
my_hash = {"host_names"=>["batman", "robin"],
           "files"=>["file1", "file2", "file3"]}

def get_log_file(h,f)
  puts "processing file #{f} for #{h}"
end

my_hash["host_names"].product(my_hash["files"]).each {|h,f| get_log_file(h, f)}
  #=>  processing file file1 for batman
  #    processing file file2 for batman
  #    processing file file3 for batman
  #    processing file file1 for robin
  #    processing file file2 for robin
  #    processing file file3 for robin
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters, you can get rid of the outer loop:

```
my_hash['host_names'].each do |host|
  my_hash['files'].each do |file|
    get_log_file(host, file)
  end
end
```

It's not any more efficient really, but a little cleaner.  I think this is going to be two loops no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you're trying to iterate over the hash's keys and then call ["something"] on each of those keys. That seems wrong.

```
    hostnames = my_hash["host_names"]
    files = my_hash["files"]

    hostnames.each do |hostname|
         files.each do |file|
             get_log_file host, file
         end
    end
```

Comment: Sorry.. there is another layer not mentioned in the example. There is an out layer which denotes the type of host (web, db, etc). Then I specify the hosts, and logs. The logs are common to both systems.